# Magento 2 How to Update current cart subtotal and grand Total?

Tags: magento2

Hello please help me to sorted out the issue

I need to update Grand Total and Subtotal of the current cart using observer in magento 2 please let me know how to do this!!!

I need cart item price total in Grand Total and Subtotal please give me step by step execution!!!

Answer (score 2):

Some Minor Correction is Required, Please Try below code

First add the `event.xml` file in your module

Directory Path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
       <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartAddObserver" />
   </event>
</config>
```

Then add observer file : `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CheckoutCartAddObserver.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CheckoutCartAddObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

     $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
     $item->getQuote()->collectTotals();
     $customSubtotal = 100; //You can set your custom subtotal amount
     $customGrandTotal = 200; //You can set your custom Grand total amount
     $updatedSubtotal = $item->getQuote()->setSubtotal($customSubtotal); 
     $updatedGrandTotal = $item->getQuote()->setGrandTotal($customGrandTotal);               
   }
}
```

After code change run below command

```
1) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
3) php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4) php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: @KapilParmar, If answer is useful please accept and upvote.

Comment: is checkout_cart_product_add_after event will trigger after adding each product to the cart.

Comment: @Hitesh Balpande, Yes it is a trigger after adding each product to the cart.

Comment: -1 because it update subtotal only mini cart, when go to cart or checkout page it show default magento subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

First add the `event.xml` file in your module

Path should be like: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
       <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Alert" />
   </event>
</config>
```

Then add observer file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Alert.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Alert implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$item->getQuote()->collectTotals();
$subtotal = $item->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $item->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();         

}
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i need to set Grand Total and Sub total!!!